# An example of a logical opposite value of a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, unary-operator

I am trying to understand unary operators in javascript, and found this reference guide here http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_are_unary_operators_in_javascript, I understand most of the examples but I am trying to work out how I would use this:

```
!a; // Logical opposite of a in an example.
```

For instance if I do this:

```
a = true;
!a;
document.writeln(a);
```

I thought this would be false, but it outputs true.

What is a good code example where I can use something along the lines of **!a** to see how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't assigning `!a` to any variable. `a` is still true.

What you want to do is this,

```
a = true;
a = !a;
document.writeln(a);
```

Comment: This definitely makes sense, however what I don't understand from that page I listed ([http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_are_unary_operators_in_javascript](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_are_unary_operators_in_javascript)) is that most of the 'unary operators' to the best of my knowledge allow you to change a value without assigning them to a value. For instance if you do `a=0; a++; document.writeln(a);` a will = 1. I was thinking that the fact they could operate alone makes then unary operators, but perhaps thats not the case?

Comment: Yeah, thats true for a++, a--, ++a, --a. But not for !a, +a, -a.

Comment: Is there a technical term/name for what a++, a--, ++a, --a does? In other words something that changes it's value in a stand alone manner?

Comment: Not really, but these are the only operators other than those involving assignment that have [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Evil_skunk, you don't store the value. So you have to do either this:

```
document.writeln(!a);
```

or this:

```
a = !a;
document.writeln(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

the value of `!a` is `false`, but you don't save the new value of `a`, so the outputted `a` is still `true`.

Try:

```
document.writeln(!a);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = !a;
```

You didn't assign the result of `!a` into the variable. Try this.